# Text Inside <map> Html

Tags: html, dictionary, src, area

I am trying to create a Kansas map with different areas.

There is a total of 7 areas and I would like to name each area Region 1, 2,... and so on.

I have created the map with the appropriate areas and coordinates that I would like to use.

The code is

```html
<img id="Image-Maps-Com-image-maps-2014-11-17-112330" src="http://www.image-maps.com/m/private/0/u7i8og3pjd1bujpjmdnl1r3533_stout20.gif" border="0" width="865" height="484" orgWidth="865" orgHeight="484" usemap="#image-maps-2014-11-17-112330" alt="" />
<map name="image-maps-2014-11-17-112330" id="ImageMapsCom-image-maps-2014-11-17-112330">
  <area shape="rect" coords="863,482,865,484" alt="Image Map" style="outline:none;" title="Image Map" href="http://www.image-maps.com/index.php?aff=mapped_users_0" />
  <area alt="" title="" href="http://www.image-maps.com/" shape="poly" coords="587,47,588,104,572,104,572,149,583,150,584,166,620,168,620,200,632,201,632,212,638,287,678,287,679,252,724,250,724,210,770,208,768,178,784,174,784,148,792,147,762,102,784,64,736,44"
  style="outline:none;" target="_self" />
  <area alt="" title="" href="http://www.image-maps.com/" shape="poly" coords="771,208,768,176,784,174,784,147,816,154,817,207" style="outline:none;" target="_self" />
  <area alt="" title="" href="http://www.image-maps.com/" shape="poly" coords="637,287,636,212,632,212,632,202,620,201,621,170,584,167,583,150,572,150,572,104,588,104,587,47,414,48,416,244,473,242,474,288,554,289,555,301,637,299" style="outline:none;" target="_self"
  />
  <area alt="" title="" href="http://www.image-maps.com/" shape="poly" coords="54,40,47,212,240,218,415,220,414,48,242,46" style="outline:none;" target="_self" />
  <area alt="" title="" href="http://www.image-maps.com/" shape="poly" coords="48,213,39,436,304,444,302,394,303,334,302,220" style="outline:none;" target="_self" />
  <area alt="" title="" href="http://www.image-maps.com/" shape="poly" coords="623,442,303,443,303,394,302,335,302,277,302,220,416,221,416,243,474,243,472,288,478,290,555,288,554,300,620,300" style="outline:none;" target="_self" />
  <area alt="" title="" href="http://www.image-maps.com/" shape="poly" coords="623,442,620,300,638,299,638,288,678,288,679,252,724,251,724,210,816,208,820,297,824,436,730,440" style="outline:none;" target="_self" />
</map>
```

Comment: Looks ok! Whats wrong....? Tipe in the title attribute.

Comment: An explanation of what you're looking to do or more clarity on what problem you're encountering would be helpful.

Comment: Do I just add text in between the title=""? Like the first one make it <area alt="" title="Region 1">?  I have added it and it did nothing. This is my first time using the <map> code.

Comment: If you hover the area then it shows

Comment: I am looking to make each area link to a specific page, and I want each area to say Region 1, 2, and so on. As in, I want the first area to say Region 1 when displaying the map.

Comment: I want Region 1 to always be showing, as in a fix text

Comment: Edit the href attribute for your needs.

Comment: I think you should edit the background image (http://www.image-maps.com/m/private/0/u7i8og3pjd1bujpjmdnl1r3533_stout20.gif) with a image programm (e.g. gimp)

Comment: So you want the text "CHEYENNE" to be "Region 1"?

Comment: How do I add a picture? I could easily show you what I want but I cannot figure that out

Comment: You allready have a picture.... I give up

Comment: As in a picture showing what I want...